# Does Spotify REALLY want my Facebook password? Isn't it against Facebook's privacy policy/TOS?

Tags: spotify

I'm surprised that Facebook supports them

[image]

(and yes, they really want Facebook password)

As of their [policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), it should be disallowed to request password from user's

> You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects Facebook usernames or passwords.

So what is going on ? Is that just some exception?

Comment: It's the biggest thing besides games that proves FB is a viable platform, so don't be surprised if there are exceptions.

Comment: Well isn't your Spotify account linked with Facebook, so that in the end you're just logging into Facebook, which authenticates your login for Spotify? I don't see the problem with that.

Comment: @slhck: "I'm just logging into Facebook" - by giving them my password, the most confidential property of mine. Well, I have tried to give them password from one member of my family which doesn't want to be on Facebook anymore, and it seems that she has received a lot of emails trying to say they that there were logging attempts from Spotify. So really, Spotify gets your real Facebook (not spotify) account email and tries to logs in to the Facebook account. Who knows what would it mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would normally be cause for alarm and against Facebook's TOS, but in this case Spotify and Facebook have entered into a direct agreement.

See: [TheRegister's acticle](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/27/zuckerberg_reservation_and_the_future_of_content_platforms/) and one at [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2011/09/27/the-facebook-spotify-deal-cui-bono/) for further detail.

Answer (score 4):

This is way after the fact, but I feel compelled to add this answer anyway.  In my opinion, this is the best way to login to Spotify via Facebook.

Facebook provides an authentication method called [Application Specific Passwords](https://www.facebook.com/help/249378535085386/) (since Oct. 27, 2011).  If you head over to your Facebook security settings, there's a section titled 'App Passwords.'  From here, you can give it the name of the application you'd like to authenticate (in this case Spotify).  Press continue and Facebook will generate a single-use random password that you can use to login to Spotify.

Comment: Side note: Google provides an analogous service that you can use to login to third party services.  Application-specific passwords and two-step verification using a mobile phone are excellent ways to add an additional level of security to your online identity.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what kind of agreement Facebook and Spotify may have, Facebook's Statement of Rights and Responsibilities ([TOS](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms)), is an agreement between Facebook and users and it currently states that

> You will not share your password (or in the case of developers, your secret key), let anyone else access your account, or do anything else that might jeopardize the security of your account.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, I was able to retrieve a user id (numeric) and a password by using https://www.spotify.com/en/account/set-device-password/. This username/password worked for logging in with the desktop application as well.